# Javascript транслит

Tags: javascript

Как в данной функции возвращать текст, исключая символы, которых нет в arrru? К примеру, %#@ ...

```js
function textTransform(text){
  var arrru = [ 'Я','я','Ю','ю','Ч','ч','Ш','ш','Щ','щ','Ж','ж','А','а','Б','б','В','в','Г','г','Д','д','Е','е','Ё','ё','З','з','И','и','Й','й','К','к','Л','л','М','м','Н','н', 'О','о','П','п','Р','р','С','с','Т','т','У','у','Ф','ф','Х','х','Ц','ц','Ы','ы','Ь','ь','Ъ','ъ','Э','э', ' ' ];
  var arren = [ 'Ya','ya','Yu','yu','Ch','ch','Sh','sh','Sh','sh','Zh','zh','A','a','B','b','V','v','G','g','D','d','E','e','E','e','Z','z','I','i','J','j','K','k','L','l','M','m','N','n', 'O','o','P','p','R','r','S','s','T','t','U','u','F','f','H','h','C','c','Y','y','`','`','\'','\'','E', 'e', '-' ];

  for(var i=0; i<arrru.length; i++){
    var reg = new RegExp(arrru[i], "g");
    text = text.replace(reg, arren[i]);
  }
  
  return text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```js
function textTransform(text){
  var arrru = [ 'Я','я','Ю','ю','Ч','ч','Ш','ш','Щ','щ','Ж','ж','А','а','Б','б','В','в','Г','г','Д','д','Е','е','Ё','ё','З','з','И','и','Й','й','К','к','Л','л','М','м','Н','н', 'О','о','П','п','Р','р','С','с','Т','т','У','у','Ф','ф','Х','х','Ц','ц','Ы','ы','Ь','ь','Ъ','ъ','Э','э', ' ' ];
  var arren = [ 'Ya','ya','Yu','yu','Ch','ch','Sh','sh','Sh','sh','Zh','zh','A','a','B','b','V','v','G','g','D','d','E','e','E','e','Z','z','I','i','J','j','K','k','L','l','M','m','N','n', 'O','o','P','p','R','r','S','s','T','t','U','u','F','f','H','h','C','c','Y','y','`','`','\'','\'','E', 'e', '-' ];

  var reg = new RegExp("[^" + arrru.join('') + "a-zA-Z]", "g");
  
  text = text.replace(reg, "");

  for(var i=0; i<arrru.length; i++){
      var reg = new RegExp(arrru[i], "g");
      text = text.replace(reg, arren[i]);
  }

  return text;
}

console.log(textTransform("ян;jjв"));
```

Comment: Код не работает для латиницы!

Comment: @GlebTer я обновил ответ

Comment: `join` без параметров объединяет через разделитель запятую

Comment: @Grundy спасибо! Я не знал. Исправил